# Nice way to get all the numbers of certain length from a text file

Tags: python

I have a file from where I want to get all 6 digits numbers (id), they are not always surrounded with a whitespace, but they don't touch other numbers (biggest number has 6 digits). In the file there are also other smaller irrelevant numbers.

I came up with this solution, that works as intended, however I wonder if there is more elegant way

```
print [num for num in "".join([e if e in "0123456789, " else " "
       for e in whole_file ]).split() if len(num) == 6]
```

Comment: have you tried regex..?

Comment: *I wonder if there is more elegant way* rip it apart and spread it out over 4 or 5 or 6 lines

Comment: You should be able to extract it via `regex`. Please provide us a sample data set along with your attempts so far.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use regex for matching.

```
\D[\d]{6}\D
```

Will match exactly 6 digits

```
\D    will match non-digit (whatever you have that separates your numbers)
\d    matches 0-9
{6}   means 6 times
```

Answer (score 2):

A combination of [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) should do it.

```
>>> import re
>>> textstring = '''123456 here is 213 some text 098234 sprea12d about
... here on 432 multiple8765 lines 999999 lets se888888e
... if it 656565 can 65656 catch432 them 34 4567 all 333333'''
>>> re.findall('\d{6}', textstring, re.MULTILINE)
['123456', '098234', '999999', '888888', '656565', '333333']
```

Comment: will it match the start of 19238192831923892118928938913289

Comment: @taesu According to the question, the biggest number has 6 digits. So this is not an issue.